# Add UserControl to a StackPanel Dynamically

Tags: wpf, silverlight, user-controls, addition, stackpanel

I have a UserControl that has some components.I need to add this UserControl to a StackPanel dynamically.If i have 5 Object in my database,i want to add 5 UserControl to this StackPanel.

I tried this to implementation :

XAML CODE for UserControl :

```
<UserControl x:Class="Islem.TeknikDestek.UI.TD11"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="411" d:DesignWidth="600" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:Islem.Silverlight.Control;assembly=Islem.Silverlight.Control">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

    <--Components -->

</Grid>
```

And C#

```
    void obj_GetAllFAQCompleted(object sender, GetAllFAQCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < e.Result.Count; i++)
                {
                    spQuestions.Children.Add(new TD11(e.Result[i]));
                }

        }
    }
```

After these,StackPanel Shows the user controls but all of components in UserControl are disabled.

What Am i missing?

Comment: `What Am i missing?` - you're missing how to use WPF properly. creating or manipulating UI elements in procedural code in WPF is discouraged and most of the time a bad idea and just plain wrong. The right way to implement items-based UIs in WPF is using an [**ItemsControl**](http://drwpf.com/blog/itemscontrol-a-to-z/)

Comment: Should i use ItemsControl instead StackPanel?

Comment: yes, a `Panel` is just a panel. If you need an items-based UI which can display many items and use proper DataBinding, you need an `ItemsControl` with a proper `ItemTemplate`. I suggest you read the link in my previous comment

Comment: I can't find something about UserControl in this article.I want to add UserControl pages to ItemsControl.Which DataBinding i can use?Without binding, i added my pages to ItemsControl.Items list.I can see the pages and their components but all of these components are disabled.I can not click a button for example.

Comment: post your current code and XAML, including the data you're using to populate the UserControl and the UserControl itself.

Comment: Ok,i handled it.It's not about StackPanel or ItemsControl.Its about my busy indicator object.Thanks for all helping.